# How to add a nice legend to a d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have my pie chart working ok but I would like to add a nice legend kind of like this (made in mspaint)

[image]

but can't quite make it work...

Here is my pie chart code (without the legend part) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var newData = [{
        count: 1,
        emote: "OneTwoThree"
      }, {
        count: 1,
        emote: "FourFiveSix"
      }, {
        count: 1,
        emote: "SevenEightNine"
      }, {
        count: 15,
        emote: "TenElevenTwelve"
      },

    ]

    // Define size & radius of donut pie chart
    var width = 450,
      height = 800,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    // Define arc colours
    var colour = d3.scale.category20();

    // Define arc ranges
    var arcText = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);

    // Determine size of arcs
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 130)
      .outerRadius(radius - 10);

    // Create the donut pie chart layout
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.count;
      })
      .sort(null);

    // Append SVG attributes and append g to the SVG
    var mySvg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var svg = mySvg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

    var svgText = mySvg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

    // Define inner circle
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", 100)
      .attr("fill", "#fff");

    // Calculate SVG paths and fill in the colours
    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(newData))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    // Append the path to each g
    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      //.attr("data-legend", function(d, i){ return parseInt(newData[i].count) + ' ' + newData[i].emote; })
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colour(i);
      });

    var textG = svg.selectAll(".labels")
      .data(pie(newData))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "labels");

    // Append text labels to each arc
    textG.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "#fff")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.data.count > 0 ? d.data.emote : '';
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm surprised there's not more "stock" examples of this sort of thing.

Here's a quickie legend that looks nice with your data:

```
// again rebind for legend
var legendG = mySvg.selectAll(".legend") // note appending it to mySvg and not svg to make positioning easier
  .data(pie(newData))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + (width - 110) + "," + (i * 15 + 20) + ")"; // place each legend on the right and bump each one down 15 pixels
  })
  .attr("class", "legend");   

legendG.append("rect") // make a matching color rect
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colour(i);
  });

legendG.append("text") // add the text
  .text(function(d){
    return d.value + "  " + d.data.emote;
  })
  .style("font-size", 12)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("x", 11);
```

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var newData = [{
        count: 1,
        emote: "OneTwoThree"
      }, {
        count: 1,
        emote: "FourFiveSix"
      }, {
        count: 1,
        emote: "SevenEightNine"
      }, {
        count: 15,
        emote: "TenElevenTwelve"
      },

    ]

    // Define size & radius of donut pie chart
    var width = 450,
      height = 800,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5;

    // Define arc colours
    var colour = d3.scale.category20();

    // Define arc ranges
    var arcText = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);

    // Determine size of arcs
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 130)
      .outerRadius(radius - 10);

    // Create the donut pie chart layout
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.count;
      })
      .sort(null);

    // Append SVG attributes and append g to the SVG
    var mySvg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var svg = mySvg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

    var svgText = mySvg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

    // Define inner circle
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", 100)
      .attr("fill", "#fff");

    // Calculate SVG paths and fill in the colours
    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(newData))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    // Append the path to each g
    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      //.attr("data-legend", function(d, i){ return parseInt(newData[i].count) + ' ' + newData[i].emote; })
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colour(i);
      });

    var textG = svg.selectAll(".labels")
      .data(pie(newData))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "labels");

    // Append text labels to each arc
    textG.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "#fff")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.data.count > 0 ? d.data.emote : '';
      });
    
    var legendG = mySvg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(pie(newData))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i){
        return "translate(" + (width - 110) + "," + (i * 15 + 20) + ")";
      })
      .attr("class", "legend");   
    
    legendG.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colour(i);
      });
    
    legendG.append("text")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.value + "  " + d.data.emote;
      })
      .style("font-size", 12)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("x", 11);
    
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create another div next to where you display your chart, and create the legend using ul/li elements. You can match the colors easily and use the names. Then you can use css for placement and styling pretty easily.

Comment: I would to keep using d3 for the legend display all in 1 svg

Comment: Have you tried checking out some of the tutorials found on google? ex: http://bl.ocks.org/ZJONSSON/3918369

Comment: Yes but I have difficulties positioning the legend when the coordinate system is defined with radius rather than x and y

Comment: Did you try adding a .attr('transform', function(d0....  after adding the g attributes for the legend? Then you can do a translation to the desired x, y positions. To designate a position based on your radius, just compute the values you want for the x,y positon based on the radius from inside the function(d) part and return the final value for both the x, y portion of the translate function.

Comment: Also, if you have a version with a working legend, I'd recommend updating the code snippet and then asking the specific question you have remaining. This will hel ensure people can help you with the exact part of the problem you are currently facing and need help for (or recommend a different approach if applicable)

Comment: You could help with providing a complete answer I think :)

Comment: Hey man, I've tried offering two - the first was the the simplest, and the second (4th comment) was a suggestion based on your comment (3rd). And based on that comment, it sounds like you do know how to implement the legend with d3, but are having difficulty customizing it -ergo my suggestion of posting what you DO have for the legend code and your specific request (ie: positioning). Then someone is more likely to be able to provide you with the precise insight you are looking for.