# Add Legend in d3 Pie Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I need to add Legend in D3 Pie Chart.

This code Creating Perfect D3 Pie Chart as required.

**Pie**

```
private drawSlices() {
this.slices = this.mainContainer
  .selectAll("path")
  .remove()
  .exit()
  .data(this.pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", this.arc);

this.slices
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "0px");

this.slices
  .attr("data-legend", function(d){ return d.name})
  .attr("data-legend-pos", function(d, i) { return i; })
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + this.arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

}

**Trying to add Legend**
and this is not  working.

```
this.slices = this.mainContainer
      .selectAll("path")
      .remove()
      .exit()
      .data(this.pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", this.arc)
      .attr("data-legend", function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .attr("data-legend-pos", function(d, i) {
        return i;
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + this.arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 20 + ", 0)")
      .style("font-size", "12px");
```

Can any body help me how to add legend

Framework: Angular 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a nice legend to a d3 pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298837/how-to-add-a-nice-legend-to-a-d3-pie-chart)

Comment: @SelakaN, as I already tried but its not showing.

Comment: can you create a sample demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: This bit here is going to remove all the paths you drew for your chart. `this.mainContainer
      .selectAll("path")
      .remove()`